# How can I suppress the wrapping of many plot legends in two columns?

Tags: plotting, legending

Say I have a plot like this:

```
ListPlot[Partition[Range@12, 1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The `PlotLegends` will wrap into 2 columns. However, I want to keep one column. In the help menu I found something like

```
ListPlot[Partition[Range@12, 1], 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Column"]]
```

But there is no option how to suppress the wrapping – what I'd really like to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Partition[Range@12, 1], 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]]
```

[image]